# Stopping new tabs upon radio but click

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple GridView1 using SqlDataSource1 to pull information from a SQL table. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and all code is written in VB, not C#. Even though I know GridView1 has an auto-sorting feature available, I am using a radiobuttonlist to make it sort (via different Select Statements) because I need the selecting of the radio buttons to fire off a few other things for other departments.

When I select a specific radiobutton, databind the select statement and databind GridView1, GridView1 resorts appropriately and displays correctly, however it does so in a new tab each time.

Anyone know why a new tab is created each time and is there any way I can prevent the accumulation of new tabs?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: It sound to me that there is a link somewhere with target=_blank or a javascript that acts in the same way. It's difficult to say without seeing the code.

Comment: That was the clue I needed. In the HTML Form1 line there was a target = blank. I don't remember if I had put that there or not but its gone now and everything is working fine. The tip was much appreciated